How are the unused bits within the Commodore 1541 DOS filetype byte handled?
I am curious to learn more about how the original Commodore 1541 DOS handles the filetype byte.  This byte is the first byte for every directory entry on disk, and is not only interpreted as the filetype (SEQ, PRG, USR, REL, DEL) but also tracks if a file is locked or 'unclosed' (which I interpret to mean the file wasn't closed properly) or 'scratched'.
I've done some limited research (mostly from the book Inside Commodore DOS, page 43) and discovered the bits are interpreted like this:
Bits 0-2 control the file type:

 000 - DEL
 001 - SEQ
 010 - PRG
 011 - USR
 100 - REL

Bit 3-4 unused

Bit 5 "@ replacement"

Bit 6 locked/unlocked
Bit 7 closed/unclosed

So a (properly closed) standard PRG file would be a value of $82, or a (properly closed) locked SEQ file would be $C1.
This much (I think) I understand.
I should point out that PRG, SEQ, USR (and the less common DEL) filetypes are all (in Commodore-speak) really just sequential files; or in other words, they are a sequential stream of bytes.  Only relative (REL) files are treated differently (the whole random-access side-sector rabbit-hole).
There are some gaps in my knowledge however, and googling hasn't turned up anything useful.
First, consider bits 0-2, which could be interpreted two ways.  One interpretation (I'll call it interpretation 'A') is to say "this is a 3 bit value between 0 and 7 that defines the filetype with only types 0,1,2,3,4 being defined and types 5,6,7 as undefined".  But you could equally interpret this (interpretation 'B') as "bits 0-1 defining file types 0,1,2,3 and bit 2 being a semaphore specifically for RELative files (meaning bits 0-1 are simply ignored if bit 2 is set)".
I've tried to express this difference in the following table:
BIT   A    B
---  ---  ---
000  DEL  DEL
001  SEQ  SEQ
010  PRG  PRG
011  USR  USR 
100  REL  REL
101  ???  REL
110  ???  REL
111  ???  REL

Perhaps another way to express this would be if you were writing code to detect relative files.  Is a relative file detected by (filetype AND 7 == 4) or by (filetype AND 7 >= 4)   (I hope I am making sense.)
Next, I do not understand the purpose of bit 5.  It feels like a semaphore used during certain operations - but I haven't found anything of substance to explain the purpose of this bit.
Lastly, have bits 3 and 4 been found to have any effect (cosmetic or otherwise) or are they completely ignored by Commodore DOS.
If I find some time, I will probably run some experiments to see what effects I get by twiddling with the filetype byte - but after all these years, this must be a definitively answered question.

When you SAVE or OPEN a filename beginning with @ (or beginning with @0: to avoid a bug), you are telling the drive that you want to replace an existing file with that name. I suspect the "@ replacement" bit is probably used by the new file during this process.

@Bavi_H, thanks for the memory refresh!  Indeed, I was able to pause the emulator in the middle of a "save with replace" operation and bit 5 was set.

It's way worse :)
The authoritative answer should be found where DOS handles the byte to create a listing. Looking it up shows essentially your solution A, but using 4 bits to decode 16 possible file types, but only providing a valid table for 5 types(0..4) and garbage for all other (5..F).

Code is Documentation
What Does DOS See?
First place to look might be how DOS decodes the bits in question. Looking at this disassembly label B_C74A shows the code responsible for turning the file type bits into text:
B_C74A
        pla         ; filetype
        and #$0F    ; isolate bit 0..3
        tay         ; and use as index

        lda TblFiletype+10,Y ; 3rd char of filetype
        sta NameBuffer,X

        dex
        lda TblFiletype+5,Y  ; 2nd char of filetype
        sta NameBuffer,X
        dex

        lda TblFiletype,Y    ; 1st char of filetype
        sta NameBuffer,X

It works back to front and uses a common trick for fixed length and fixed address list items by putting the offset into the base address, that way Y does not need to be managed at all. Handy for short lists striping loop overhead.
;**  Names of file types                        
TblFiletype          ; [FEBB]
.tx     "DSPUR"      ;** 1st char
.tx     "EERSE"      ;** 2nd char
.tx     "LQGRL"      ;** 3rd char

This table will only work correctly for values 0..4. Everything past that will access random bytes from data beyond:
;**  Value of LED-byte for every drive                  
A_FECA  .by $08,$00

;**  For setting the Zero flag, see routine at 
A_FECC  .by $00

;**  Masks for bit command
A_FECD  .by $3F,$7F,$BF,$FF

;**  Number of sectors per track
A_FED1  .by  $11,$12,$13,$15

;**  Constands for disk format
A_FED5  .by  'A'           ; marker for 1541 format
A_FED6  .by  $04           ; 4 track ranges
A_FED7  .by  $24           ; number of tracks +
        .by  $1F,$19,$12   ; tracks on which sector numbers change

This will result these types:
0 -> 'D','E','L'
1 -> 'S','E','Q'
2 -> 'P','R','G'
3 -> 'U','S','R'
4 -> 'R','E','L'
5 -> 'E','L',$08  (CBM on 1581)
6 -> 'E','Q',$00
7 -> 'R','G',$00
8 -> 'S','R','?'  (*2)
9 -> 'E','L',$7F
A -> 'L',$08,$BF
B -> 'Q',$00,$FF
C -> 'G',$00,$11
D -> 'R','?',$12
E -> 'L',$7F,$13
F -> '$08,$BF,$15

How to Search
Another place to look for might be how DOS interprets a given file type for search operations, which is done by a loop at L_C3B6:
L_C3B0
        cmp     TblFiletype,Y  ; compare with 'S', 'P', 'U', 'R'
        beq     L_C3B8         ; same, ->
        dey
        bne     L_C3B0

It uses the same table, but only compares types 4..1. If not found type 0 (DEL) is assumed.
How to Open
The third part where DOS touches the file type is when an OPEN command is processed. This is done at B_DAE1:
B_DA1E
        dey
        bmi    B_DA29

        cmp    A_FEB6,Y ; file types 'D','S','P','U','L'
        bne    B_DA1E

Interestingly this uses a different table:
;**  File types
A_FEB6  .tx    "DSPUL"

Obviously wasting 5 bytes to cover L for REL files (*3)

It Continues
DOS 3.0/3.1 (1570/71) and DOS 10 (1581) use the very same logic, except that with the 1581 the tables were extended for C(BM) as file type 6 used with 'sub-drives' as seen here:
DBA5: 44 53 50 55 4C 43        DSPULC Filetypes

DBAB: 44 53 50 55 52 43        DSPURC   Filetypes
DBB1: 45 45 52 53 45 42        EERSEB   [read this vertically!]
DBB6: 4C 51 47 52 4C 4D        LQGRLM


Conclusion:
You're simply expecting way more careful coding than Commodore was willing to do - leading to their code being quite often way worse than expected. Then again, it was a different time, and who should write anything then the legal coding. Not DOS, that's sure :))

More Info
Found a very nice pagea the 'just solve' Wiki about the basic 1541 file system including a detailed description of the file type, supporting all above. So far the finest source I know.

*1 - Others I found, like this and this, show the same code, so I picked the one with the 'best' comments/label names added.
*2 - Possibly the only one that might make some sense when listed. At the same time the first that would as well mean DEL (0..2 == 0). Feels like a possible loophole :))
*3 - Given, using L is necessary to avoid confusion as R was already used as Read, still, one could have saved at least a byte here.

thank you for the fantastic answer.  I had managed to deduce the full lower nibble was being used to identify the filetype by doing some experimenting with the values.  Except for the non-printable characters, I worked out the same table as you by creating 16 files on a disk, sector editing the filetype byte to each permutation, and looking at the resulting disk directory. -  So we definitively know how bits 0-3, 6 and 7 are used, leaving bits 4 and 5.  I suspect bit 4 is completely ignored and bit 5 is somehow used when opening or saving using "@0:" (as mentioned by Bavi_h).

I just tried pausing the emulator in the middle of a "save and replace" operation and indeed, bit 5 was set.

@Geo... Oh, you were also interested in the other bits? I somehow interpreted your question being strictly about the file type, that is the lower 3(4) bits.

no worries - it was a somewhat meandering question. :-)

@Geo... I already browsed thru the sources and it seems as that @ thing is really for overwriting (it'll be tested and set in the opening code. Likewise the two other work as documented. I just can't motivate myself to form this into an all out answer. maybe tomorrow...

Files which are processed by Epyx Software's "Vorpal Disk Utilities" will have their file type set so they appear as SR?.
